# Character Handling on Mac in Java

Tags: java, macos, character-encoding

So I recently finished a program for a colleague that wanted a quick quizzing system with *very* loose encryption.

I emphasize very because the encryption is merely adding a flat number to each character in the file, thus resulting in (easily decryptable, but these are grad students in a completely unrelated field) a jarbled mess.

This works as intended in Windows and Linux, it encrypts and decrypts fine.

However, on Mac it does not.

On Mac it encrypts fine, but then when decryption kicks in, it becomes an assortment of the occasional letter and several blank spaces. I currently think it's because I have not set what charset the character array is, but is it possible to set an array (not a string) to a specific charset?

I'm currently not in a position to post code, but if people need further information before suggesting anything, I will be able to later.

Comment: You certainly cannot set a `char[]` to have a specific charset.  The char values should give the same thing if you used `char`'s to generate the encrypted file (I don't think you need to specify a charset).

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a Caesar cipher? It changes each char into an ascii number, adds a flat number to each ascii number, then reverts each char to the respective chars. If this is your encryption, you simply need to subtract your flat number in the loop for decryption.

Comment: As I said, this works in Windows and Linux, but in Mac it does not.

Comment: If it works in windows and linux, it may be a problem with the JDK/JRE you installed locally.